# Strange jQuery radio button show/hide bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the username text field to show up when op1 and op2 is selected and both text fields if op3 is selected. I have a strange bug on which any radio button selected will always show the username and password text fields. Why is this happening?

HTML:

```
<div>Please select operation:<br />
    <input type="radio" id="op1" name="op" value="check_username">Check Username<br />
    <input type="radio" id="op2" name="op" value="find_profile">Find Profile<br />
    <input type="radio" id="op3" name="op" value="check_credentials">Check Credentials
</div><br />

<div id="un">Username:<br /><input type="text" /></div>
<div id="pwd">Password:<br /><input type="text" /></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#un, #pwd').hide();
    $('input[name="op"]').prop('checked', false);
    $("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $('input:radio[name=op]').change(function() {
        var op = $('input:radio[name=op]:checked').val();
        alert(op);
        switch(op) {
            case 'check_username':
            $('#un').show();
            $('#pwd').hide();
            case 'find_profile':
            $('#un').show();
            $('#pwd').hide();
            case 'check_credentials':
            $('#un, #pwd').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it would be better if you could bind the radio buttons by ID because otherwise the whole DOM tree will be iterated to find all radio input types. Nothing major, but it would be much cleaner without having to use switch clauses.

Comment: Are you saying that I should switch by using ID cases '#op1 #op2 #op3' instead of using .val() as the cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `break` statements after each of your `case` statements. It's [working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/nma6b/) after I've added them!

Comment: If possible, please comment if there is a more efficient write my code. Thanks again.

Comment: I think what you're doing is fine. I would put a change event on radio buttons with the same name as you are doing (as their IDs shouldn't be the same). You could do simple things like store radio buttons in variable and be more specific with element selection (eg. you could select by `$('#myElement input:radio[name=op]')` if you knew your radio buttons were inside an element with the `id` of `myElement`. Have a search for _jQuery efficient selectors_.

Answer (score 0):

you've forgot the 'break' in each case:

```
    switch(op) {
        case 'check_username':
        $('#un').show();
        $('#pwd').hide();
        break;
        case 'find_profile':
        $('#un').show();
        $('#pwd').hide();
        break;
        case 'check_credentials':
        $('#un, #pwd').show();
        break;
    }
```